# Is the compiler required to inline functions in the base class that are both virtual and final?

Tags: c++

In a CppCon talk by Nicolai Josuttis (see [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WRQ1xqYBKgc) starting at 34:10), one of his suggestions for the use of the specifiers `virtual`, `override`, and `final`, is to mark either all functions virtual (for a polymorphic class) or none of them (for a standard class).

His rational for doing this is that it allows you to write functions that cannot be overridden or hidden by specifying those functions as `virtual`-`final` in the base class. He states that the compiler can just inline the function, because it is able to reason that it won't actually be virtual. It's interesting advice, because now each function in the base class means something specific depending on the specifiers you use: must be overridden, can be overridden, or cannot be overridden. It also begs the question, if your derived class can be called without polymorphism, why are you making it polymorphic at all?

Because this seemed like it could work, and some of the audience in the talk seemed to disagree with that advice, I wrote a simple program to test it out (see [here](https://godbolt.org/z/En6Eo4o9a)). It seems clang is able to inline the function, whereas for g++, the `doProcedure()` function ends up in the vtable anyway. Is the compiler required to inline these sorts of functions or could there be performance penalties when you do this?

The basic outline of the test can be seen below, however I am worried that it may be so simple that it is masking the issue.

```
class Base
{
public:
    virtual ~Base() = default;

    
    virtual void doProcedure() const final  // Cannot be overridden
    {
        preProcess();
        process();
        postProcess();
    }

protected:
    virtual void preProcess() const;        // Can be overridden
    virtual void process() const = 0;       // Must be overridden
    virtual void postProcess() const;       // Can be overridden
};

class Derived : public Base
{
public:
    virtual void process() const override;

    // error: virtual function 'virtual void Derived::doProcedure() const' overriding final function
    // void doProcedure() const {}
};
```

Comment: `inline` - when not used simply to put a definition in a header file - is a "hint" to the compiler.  Compiler doesn't have to do a darn thing to "respect" it.  It can inline what it wants, it can not inline what it wants.  It can make different decisions for the same function in different parts of the program - even when called from the same function.  Same goes for methods declared inline in a class without the `inline` keyword.

Comment: There is no guarantee that the call will be inlined, but any compiler worth it's name should be able to call the function without going through the vtable if it's marked `final` in the base class.

Comment: Yes, and if it is not `final` in the base class but is `final` in some derived class then it can be inlined if the compiler can prove the object is that derived class (or some subclass of it).  (But I've never actually verified which compilers do this and when.)

Comment: TL;DR The compiler is not required to inline anything.

Comment: @davidbak Interesting, so it seems like the advice requires you to rely on a property that could give you performance that's no better than if you hadn't marked the function virtual at all, but could also hurt you when using certain compilers

Comment: @super That makes sense, I wonder why g++ wasn't able optimize it in my test case. Seemed straight forward enough...

Comment: (I haven't seen the video yet.) The only case that could possibly _hurt_ is if you had this base class and you would have left a particular method _not_ virtual but now with this advice you marked it _virtual final_, so you might incur the cost of an indirect call rather than a direct call. (There's no storage cost: the class has at least one other virtual so it has to have a vtable.)  Presumably the advice is for software engineering reasons related to (the reader) understanding a difference between classes that allow polymorphism and those that don't.  So, that's the price you might pay. ...

Comment: ... Now ... if for some particular class (hierarchy) you _really_ don't want to pay the price (it's usually a very very small price, that indirect call) then you can: use your judgment and ignore it in this particular case; refactor the base class so it itself has a non-polymorphic parent class that has this method (if his overall advice allows a polymorphic class to have a non-polymorphic pattern); or make this method private (surely his advice - did I mention I haven't watched the video? - is only meant for public (and protected) methods?) and use it that way as a helper in the base class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is the compiler required to inline functions...

No. There are no cases where the compiler would be required by the C++ language to expand a function call inline.

Comment: ...because the standard describes only the behavior, not the details of the resulting machine code.